# Proportion of unsuccessful mod candidates who rapidly reduce their site involvement?

Tags: discussion, election, statistics

It often happens online that candidates for mod positions who fail to get elected either leave a site right away or reduce their involvement radically. This suggests that a main reason for their previous level of involvement may have been that they desired to become a moderator.

To what extent does this occur on the various SE sites? This could be measured for each site using something like the following metric: the proportion of unsuccessful mod candidates whose combined number of actions on the given site and its meta site — questions, answers and other actions — fell to less than a quarter in the post-election three months of what it was for the pre-election three months — which could then be compared to the site median for all users who have been registered for at least half as long as the median mod candidate. I'd also be interested to know the proportion of unsuccessful mod candidates whose participation falls to zero for say three months within say a week of the election result.

Comment: Its the right site. Its going to be a rediculous amount of statistics tho

Comment: Rather than  quantities immediately preceding election, I would compare to slightly older quantites. It is fine to show extra effort before  the election. As long as you don't fall behind your original commitment afterwards.

Comment: I already have the code to pull activity data (and generate graphs) from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289995/2015-moderator-candidate-activity-profiles, I could probably put something together. If I do I'll post it. It's a lot of data for one post, though, maybe I'll put it on a web site. If anybody's interested there's an SEDE query there that may help, it can be combined with stuff from the reviews page (which maybe can be pulled from SEDE as well now, I forget why I did that separately).

Comment: One of the Post types in SEDE is mod nomination, so instead of hard-wiring a list of user IDs you could look for users who've had such a post.  That wouldn't account for withdrawn nominations, but that's probably ok.  (You'd then need to sort winners from losers, and remember that some people stand for election more than once.  It won't be *easy*, but there might be some help to be found there.)

Comment: Often on small side someone will disagree with how the site is run and therefore stand for election, if they are then told by most side users "to get lost", the may do so.   So the desire to become a moderator may be part of their desire to make the side "good", but if the rest of the users don't agree with them on what "good" means....

Comment: I've also noticed that a fair amount of "failed" candidates seem to run multiple years in a row. Doesn't mean anything on its own, but there are certainly some candidates who stay active at least.